# Each time I click an "href" link it adds the link again to the URL. Why?

Tags: html, jsp, web, jakarta-ee

I've got a button that says

`<a href="home.jsp">Home</a>`

and another link

`<a href="CRUD/Books/Add.jsp">Add</a>`

If I click Home then Add it works fine but then when I click add again the URL multiplies like this

`URL: CRUD/Books/Add/CRUD/Books/Add.jsp`

and I have lots of pages with the same issue what should I do to prevent this?

Comment: I need to see your Add.jsp code. This happened to me once using python - if you print the exact same html code in a different file, you've basically replicated the html file except in a different website. Then if you click the link again, you'd go to the same page and have double, just like what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
   <a href="/CRUD/Books/Add.jsp">Add</a>
```